# How to store the previous state of a 2D array?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I want to be able to make changes to a 2D array but be able to store the previous state to use later.

For example:

**First click:**
prevArray = [] currArray = [1,0,0],

**Second click:**
prevArray = [1,0,0] currArray = [1,1,0],

**Third Click:**
prevArray = [1,1,0] currArray = [1,1,1]

```
 import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const numRows = 3;
  const numCol = 3;

  const [currentGrid, setCurrentGrid] = useState(() =>
    Array.from({ length: numRows }).map(() =>
      Array.from({ length: numCol }).fill(0)
    )
  );

  const prevGrid = usePrevious(currentGrid);

  function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    }, [value]);
    return ref.current;
  }

  const gridClick = (i, k) => {
    const newGridState = [...currentGrid];
    if (newGridState[i][k] === 1) {
      newGridState[i][k] = 0;
    } else {
      newGridState[i][k] = 1;
    }
    setCurrentGrid([...newGridState]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="grid"
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numRows},20px)`,
          marginBottom: "20px",
        }}
      >
        {currentGrid.map((rows, i) =>
          rows.map((col, k) => (
            <div
              onClick={() => gridClick(i, k)}
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                backgroundColor: currentGrid[i][k] ? "blue" : "green",
                border: "solid 1px black",
              }}
            ></div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>

      <div
        className="grid"
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numRows},20px)`,
          marginBottom: "20px",
        }}
      >
        {prevGrid != null
          ? prevGrid.map((rows, i) =>
              rows.map((col, k) => (
                <div
                  style={{
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    backgroundColor: currentGrid[i][k] ? "blue" : "green",
                    border: "solid 1px black",
                  }}
                ></div>
              ))
            )
          : console.log("empty")}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Currently the "prevGrid" useState just copies the same values that are in the "currentGrid".

Comment: You should move your `onClick` handler up to be a function constant.  As is, a new copy of the function gets created every iteration through the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some hook, just like in this example from [useHooks](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/).

In this sample they used for getting the previous value of a counter variable:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Usage
function App() {
  // State value and setter for our example
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Get the previous value (was passed into hook on last render)
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);

  // Display both current and previous count value
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Hook
function usePrevious(value) {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: I implemented the changes based on your comment (as seen in my recent edit). But still the "prevGrid" reflects the current state as the "currentGrid". Could it have something to do with the way that I am updating the currentGrid? Here is a sandbox link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-https-ikqiz.